# Did Jesus have a choice?

Tags: life-of-jesus, crucifixion

Could Jesus have opted to not go to the cross and still remain sinless? Or would that have been a sign of disobedience? Did He have a choice or not really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

1. Because Jesus is 100% human as well as 100% God, Jesus has a fully human will in his human nature.  Just like us, Jesus had free will at every turn.  Going to the cross was a completely voluntary mission out of love.  Being voluntary, it could have been rejected without making it a sin.  **So Jesus acted with full freedom, making a true choice.**
2. But as shown below, not going to the cross is a self contradiction for Jesus, because since before the incarnation this "cup of suffering" was planned.  It is *God* who assumed human nature as Jesus, how could God contradict his own will, a divine contradiction?  **So in the second sense, Jesus did not have a "choice".**
3. To resolve this, we have to properly understand what "obedience to the Father" means.  Chalcedonian definition really helps us here.  "obedience" / "submission" is *not* subjecting one's will to the will of a more powerful being,  But **"obedience" is Jesus in his human nature saying YES with gladness to *participate* and to *realize* (in the day to day execution) the plan his own divine nature (with the Father) had decided before.**
4. The great cost of going to the cross and the agony of fear in Gethsemane is simply the consequence of creaturely human nature (which we also possess) undertaking such immense mission, which Jesus gladly endured out of love.  **This submission to suffering can be seen as Jesus (in his human nature) making his desires and feelings to obey his will to love.  In his humanity he is asking the Father for strength, since in Gethsemane he freely obscured his own divine nature so he can be in solidarity with us.**

#### Longer answer

@HoldToTheRod's answer is short and to the point, and I agree with him.
However, given that in mainstream Christianity Jesus is both 100% human and also the Second Person of the Trinity (Son of God), there are unresolved questions that Trinitarian Christianity has to address.

For example:

- Given that God and the Son of God is one being, how is it possible that Jesus "disobeyed"?
- In what sense is it meaningful for Jesus to *not* want to go to the cross when the very purpose of His coming to earth is to do precisely that?
- Why couldn't God simply forgive us *by fiat*, why did Jesus have to die?
- Why is it so hard for Jesus as the Son of God to go to the cross in the first place?  Isn't he the Son of God through whom the world was created?
- How is the dialog between Jesus and the Father even possible, isn't it like talking to oneself?

Below, I try to answer your question from the perspective of Jesus as the Son of God *who takes on a human nature*, per [Chalcedonian Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcedonian_Definition).  In my previous answers that deal with this topic ([here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89454/10672), [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89831/10672), and [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/86668/10672)), I cited Eleonore Stump [explaining how exactly Jesus is both God and man at the same time](https://www.closertotruth.com/interviews/58405): how Jesus never lose his divinity but can choose to operate *ONLY* in his human nature *temporarily* so that Jesus could truly see and feel the world around him as we do.

**My answer below will explore all the significance of Jesus's having this choice and freedom in going to the cross, from the incarnation perspective.**

#### Did Jesus have a true choice?

I'm going to answer YES, in light of the 3 points below about the meaning and purpose of incarnation.

Firstly, as [Eleonore Stump explained](https://www.closertotruth.com/interviews/58405), incarnation means that Jesus is a *single* integrated individual that looks 100% human, but who can access *both* his human and divine natures.  At any particular moment **Jesus can *freely choose* whether to access his human nature only (temporarily obscuring his divine nature), his divine nature only, or both at the same time**.  So in some of Jesus's acts his divinity shines (forgiving sins, doing miracles, knowing what people think); in other acts his humanity shines (didn't realize his parents were looking for him when he was 12, growing in wisdom and stature, weeping for Lazarus, fearful in Gethsemane, etc.).

Secondly, we need to remember that one of the several purposes of Jesus as the Second Person of the Trinity to assume human nature (*cf*. [Phil 2:6-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians+2%3A6-11&version=NLT)) to **show solidarity with the humans He created by being incarnate as an everyday unprivileged human being.**  This is God's way of saying "I'm with you",  being aware of all the limitations of living as a creature living in the least desirable corner of the Roman empire.  That is also why Jesus was befriending repentant sinners, social outcast, and the unjustly oppressed.

Thirdly, the human nature that God "wears" is free from the power of sin (and of original sin), so all his acts in his human nature is unencumbered by concupiscence (disordered desires).  Why is this important?  One reason is so he could truly be a Second Adam, a "redo".  **God is showing us**

1. **what Adam could have accomplished if he didn't eat the fruit that led to his spiritual death**, and
2. **a perfect human being who loves God perfectly and who loves our neighbors perfectly, a role model to imitate**.

For this purpose, it is obvious that Jesus would need to have exactly the same kind of will that human beings have.

**CONCLUSION**: In light of the two purposes of incarnation described above (solidarity and moral exemplar) Jesus would have possessed the same kind of free will that ordinary human beings possess, although in his case it is unencumbered by the effects of original sin.  Otherwise we cannot meaningfully imitate Jesus (in his human nature).

#### Could Jesus have refused his mission and remain sinless?

This is a hypothetical question, **so I'm going to answer speculatively (!!)**, just so that we can appreciate better of how God saves us through incarnation.

- YES, Jesus in his human nature could have refused his mission, but then it would have created a conflict with Jesus in his divine nature who wanted to save humanity through his mission.
- YES, Jesus in his human nature would have remained sinless (I emphasize *human nature*, because divine nature cannot sin by definition).  Why?  Jesus was NOT under a moral obligation to sacrifice himself.  Jesus could have been a sinless Jew doing good to others and teaching them about God as a 1st century AD Jew living in that corner of the Roman empire.

  It wasn't as if Jesus was drafted as a soldier as in today's Israel / South Korea / Singapore where every male needs to undergo a short military training and be ready to serve when needed.  In other words, we should NOT see Jesus obeying the Father like a dutiful soldier who would be sinning by deserting his duty.

  Although doing one's duty is a form of love, to show us perfect love it is important that the mission to undergo suffering for us is completely optional and voluntary, done out of perfect love for us.  A modern equivalent would be the Catholic notion of [Evangelical counsels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelical_counsels) where people who desire to love God and neighbors more radically (like Jesus), would renounce the world by taking a voluntary vow of poverty, celibacy, and obedience (again, like Jesus).

**CONCLUSION**: Yes, Jesus (in his human nature) could have refused the mission and remained sinless.  But by doing this, humanity would not be saved, only taught like how Moses taught Israel.  Even worse, this is a theoretical impossibility since how can God frustrates his own plan: a self-contradiction?

#### Understanding the apparent conflict of wills

Now that we have settled how Jesus in his human nature had to die on the cross voluntarily out of love, how are we then to understand Jesus's prayer to let the "cup of suffering" be taken away ([Mt 26:36-39, Mk 14:32-36, Lk 22:41-44](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mt+26%3A36-39%2C+Mk+14%3A32-36%2C+Lk+22%3A41-44&version=NLT) followed by "Yet I want your will to be done, not mine", which is also affirmed more positively in [Jn 18:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2018%3A11&version=NLT) as "Shall I not drink from the cup of suffering the Father has given me?"  How do we solve the apparent conflict of 2 wills or the existence of 2 persons?  **How do we properly understand "obedience" since we ruled out the notion of a soldier obeying out of mere duty?**

This is where the doctrine of Chalcedonian incarnation truly shines, where there is only one person but two natures. I think we can understand it in two ways:

1. [*Dyothelitism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyothelitism) conceives that there are 2 wills or 2 modes of operations corresponding to the 2 natures of Jesus.  Prior to incarnation, Jesus in his divine nature *already* planned the path that Jesus in his human nature was going to take, a plan formed in love of humanity.  During Jesus's mission, **the will in his human nature voluntarily chose to realize his own divine plan *day by day***.  From [CCC 475](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/para/475.htm):

   > Similarly, at the sixth ecumenical council, Constantinople III in 681, the Church confessed that Christ possesses two wills and two natural operations, divine and human. They are not opposed to each other, but cooperate in such a way that the Word made flesh willed humanly in obedience to his Father all that he had decided divinely with the Father and the Holy Spirit for our salvation. Christ's human will "does not resist or oppose but rather submits to his divine and almighty will."
2. In Gethsemane, Jesus chose to access ONLY his *human nature*, thus being in solidarity with every one of us who is in agony to glorify our Father in heaven through the voluntary choice of a difficult mission of love.  In his human nature Jesus was battling the conflict between his *desire* to preserve himself (constituent of the natural order, thus morally okay) and his loving *intention* to continue his mission which requires him (if he accepts) to drink "the cup of suffering".  Instead of using *Dyothelitism* "your will to be done, not mine" may also be interpreted *not* as the existence of two wills but **as his exertion to make his desires align with his will to suffer**.  This is similar to soldiers in the eve of battle.

**CONCLUSION**: There are many verses implying that Jesus was devoted to obeying His Father.  Many Christians say that this includes going to the cross, as a supreme example of obedience, **as though submission to death *in itself* is a virtue**!  In my opinion this makes the Father look like a tyrant who if not obeyed results in one sinning against the all powerful God.  One disobedience, and you go to hell.  Who can love such a God?

In my opinion, it is much better (and consistent with Jesus's two natures) to see "obedience" and "submission" as the human Jesus **agreeing at every turn with his own pre-conceived divine plan to love humanity**: the human saying YES with the Father out of desire to love, including drinking the cup of suffering.

#### More appreciation of what Jesus has done for us

Having established the purpose of incarnation and the voluntary nature of Jesus's mission (in his human nature), I hope we can now appreciate what Jesus was going through mentally and psychologically as He sojourned with us on earth.  **God could have forgiven us *by fiat*, but that's not the way He chose**.  He wanted to save us while *simultaneously* being in solidarity with us so that in the plan of salvation Jesus also became a moral exemplar for us:

- to arouse our love for God (in response to Jesus's sacrifice)
- to arouse our solidarity with the oppressed around us (because Jesus did it first)
- to show how it IS possible to love God perfectly (because Jesus demonstrated it)

Although Jesus's mission was his own (i.e. God did not call us to fulfill OT prophecies such as [Ps 22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ps+22&version=NLT) and [Isa 53](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isa+53&version=NLT)), **we can still learn from Ps 22 and Isa 53 as a pattern of loving others, since Jesus in his human nature was a willing "solder" / "hero" / "victim" who completed his mission out of true love, not simply out of duty / obedience**.

- In the *first part* of [Ps 22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ps+22&version=NLT) we can read as Jesus's plea to God for strength in the moment of crucifixion (and in whatever suffering / struggle that we incur for following Jesus) while in the *second part* of Ps 22 we can read as Jesus's affirmation of faith in God who **will** save him (just as we have the sure hope of resurrection when we feel we cannot go further while in the service of love).
- In [Isa 53](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isa+53&version=NLT) we can read Jesus as the suffering servant through whom humanity will be absolved from their sin. Of course we are not absolving anyone's sin, but while we are persecuted by our enemies we can

  - know that Jesus is with us when everyone else despises / abandons us (v. 3)
  - know that Jesus truly understands us when others (like Job's friends) think we are punished by God for our suffering (v. 4b-5a)
  - be gracious when we suffer because of other's sin (v. 4a,6)
  - know we are not alone when we are unjustly condemned (v. 8a,8b)
  - give our lives to defend our family / friends / country to save them from aggression (v. 8c)
  - have strong hope in the midst of our suffering that the payoff is satisfaction (v. 11), that we will receive honors of a victorious soldier (v. 12) and that we will enjoy prosperous eternal life in the life to come (v. 10)

Comment: I feel like you have put more effort into understanding the spirit of my question even if you disagree with its premise. I only asked it because I e heard it used as an argument for God’s love and that had he rejected going to the cross he would have remained perfectly holy and righteous. Something I don’t know I agree with. Technically God could distort this universe and start again. And know one but he would know but it would go against his character to start over every time something doesn’t go his way. Especially when freewilled beings are in the picture.

Comment: @Autodidact I extensively reworked the example.  Hopefully it addresses more of "the spirit of your question".

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Jesus' sacrifice was voluntary.

Luke records Jesus saying in Gethsemane:

> Father, if thou be willing, remove this cup from me: nevertheless not
> my will, but thine, be done. (Luke 22:42)

This act of submission to the Father's will is irrelevant if Jesus was compelled to proceed.

The Epistle to the Hebrews compares the Levitical high priest, who was himself in bondage to sin, and had to make an offering for his own sins as well as the people's, and contrasts this with Christ, who was able to mediate humanity's debt to justice because He was in no such bondage:

> 7 But into the second went the high priest alone once every year, not
> without blood, which he offered for himself, and for the errors of the
> people
>
> ...
>
> 14 How much more shall the blood of Christ, who through the eternal
> Spirit offered himself without spot to God, purge your conscience from
> dead works to serve the living God?
>
> 15 And for this cause he is the mediator of the new testament (Hebrews
> 9:7, 14-15)

If Jesus didn't have a choice then His sacrifice wasn't voluntary. He qualified as the mediator because He wasn't legally bound.

---

**Post-script for clarification**

If it would have been sinful for Jesus to not perform the atonement, then His atoning sacrifice *would* have been required of Him for His own salvation. The epistle to the Hebrews indicates that the Levitical high priest had to sacrifice for himself and the people, and contrasts this with Christ, who atoned for others but had no need to do so for Himself.

If Jesus was coerced, or faced dire consequences for not performing the atonement, then His sacrifice wasn't truly voluntary. Ergo, there was no law or commandment He would be breaking had He declined to atone. Jesus' sacrifice was entirely voluntary.

Comment: "*This act of submission to the Father's is not relevant if Jesus was compelled to proceed.*" Wonderfully said! +1 ;)

Comment: I feel as though you missed the spirit of the question entirely. Isaac voluntarily obeyed his father Abraham, but the question isn’t that, it’s whether Jesus would have sinned had he decided, no this is too much, it’s not worth it, humans are obstinate et cetera, could he have remained righteous had he chosen to leave earth and not go through with the ultimate sacrifice?

Comment: @Autodidact I added a PS to clarify the inference I have made

Comment: It’s an interesting perspective Rod, **“Then I said, ‘Behold, I have come to do your will, O God, as it is written of me in the scroll of the book.’””
‭‭Hebrews‬ ‭10:7‬** coerced or not, it was expected of Him and had He refused, in my mind it would have constituted disobedience not an insignificant, inconsequential, unimportant detail.

Answer (score 1):

What was the required response in the Garden? Adam had to resist eating of the wrong tree. God’s will was for Adam to eat of any *other* tree. To eat of the wrong tree, by following temptation, was contrary to God’s will.

Jesus as the second and last Adam had the same requirement. To do God’s will or to be tempted to do another will. There is only 1 other will that opposes God, that of the devil.

We know that Jesus faced temptation his whole fleshly life, right up until death.

> He in the days of His flesh, having offered up both prayers and supplications with loud crying and tears to the One being able to save him from death, and having been heard because of reverent submission Heb 5:17

Yes, of course Jesus had a choice, but there was only one righteous choice - to live according to God’s will. Jesus had his own will which faced constant influence by the devil. Hence his earnest prayer for the Father’s provisions. To *resist* the cup of final suffering, we are clearly told, was *not* the Father’s will, but his own.

Comment: Right, he had a choice but if he would have chosen to reject the crucifixion he would have sinned. Which essentially means he had no choice if he wanted to remain sinless and righteous.

Comment: Of course he *wanted* to remain sinless (I and the Father are one) but he still had to resist temptation and choose correctly. If he did not, it would have been sinful and the whole Saviour thing ruined. This is reinforced by him having his own will which differed from God’s.

Comment: I agreed with you hence the “right”

Answer (score -3):

*Could Jesus have opted to not go to the cross and still remain sinless? Or would that have been a sign of disobedience? Did He have a choice or not really?*

**Disobedience is a sin**, and if Jesus opted not to accept the cross, it is a violation of God's Greatest Commandment.

*The disobedience or "non-serviam" of Lucifer cast him out in the Heavenly realms.*

*The disobedience of Adam cast him out in the Garden of Eden.*

Loving means obeying God's Will.

> **The Greatest Commandment**
> …36“Teacher, which commandment is the greatest in the Law?” 37 Jesus declared, “‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’ 38This is the first and greatest commandment.-Matthew22:37

Did Jesus have a choice? Yes!, but the anointing of the Holy Spirit at baptism of Jordan empower Jesus to obey and follow God's Will until the end, even unto death.

The anointing of Jesus as "Christ", bestowed upon the greatest gifts of the Holy Spirit.

> **The Attitude of Christ**
> …7but emptied Himself, taking the form of a servant, being made in human likeness. 8And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself and became obedient to death— even death on a cross.

> The name Jesus means "Savior."

> The Meaning of Jesus’ Name as Savior
> As stated above, Jesus means savior. This is His special role. He saves his people from the guilt of sin, by cleansing them in His own atoning blood. He saves them from the dominion of sin by putting in their hearts the sanctifying Spirit. He saves them from the presence of sin, when He takes them out of this world to rest with Him. He will save them from all the consequences of sin, when He shall give them a glorious body at the last day.

> Those seeking salvation may draw near to the Father with boldness and have access with confidence through Christ. It is His role and His delight to show mercy. **"For God didn't send his Son into the world to judge the world, but that the world should be saved through him,"** (John 3:17).

https://www.christianity.com/jesus/is-jesus-god/names-of-jesus/what-does-the-name-jesus-mean.html

**Jesus means Saviour,** can Jesus betray the meaning of His very name? Especially after the anointing of the Holy Spirit was upon Him?

**The answer is a BIG NO!**

Jesus anointed as Christ, knew His identity and mission clearly.

> **For I have come down from heaven not to do my will but to do the will of him who sent me.**-John6:38

Besides how can Jesus not accept the Cross, when the Cross is the Tree of Life, and the Tree of Life is the Blessed Virgin Mary.

https://stmatthewbt.org/2015/03/08/the-cross-of-christ-the-tree-of-life-1-corinthians-118-31/

https://www.immanueljoplin.com/services-and-sermons/the-tree-of-life-to-the-cross/

*If the Tree or Life is the Cross, who is the Tree of Life?*

The Tree of Life is the Theotokos, and Jesus is Her firstfruit. That's why when scriptures said, *"Behold the Cross" it means "Behold thy Mother".*

https://thelegionofmaryri.com/2019/08/02/mary-is-the-tree-of-life/

> Wisdom is the Cross and the Cross is Wisdom. -St.Montfort

Jesus became the Wisdom of God. -1Corinthians1-30

And Mary became the Seat of Wisdom. -Proverbs9:1 and Sirach24:8

> “Then the Creator of all gave me his command, and my Creator chose the spot for my tent.

Comment: Remove the Roman Catholic references which have nothing to do with the reformed evangelical church and you get a +1, that part is absolutely irrelevant to the question entirely.

Comment: @Autodidact   If they are in communion with Rome, I see no problem with Evangelicals. I cannot remove Catholic Church reference, they are the Church founded by Christ .-Ave!